# How to profile performance of passive effects in React (Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-devtools

I have a React Native project and I'm currently looking into performance using the flamegraph in React Devtools.

Now it's telling me a lot of time in some renders is spent on "Passive effects". Example:

[image]

According to Google these are mostly tied to `useEffect`s. However, the problem is that React Devtools doesn't tell me anything about *which* effects are taking the longest. Given that the project is quite big, I can't just go around every `useEffect` and log its timing in the console.

I found it quite strange that the information is so cryptic and limited. Is there any way to just generate a list of all passive effects for a specific render and their time consumption?